# Process (CMD) is not closed hence no new process can be started

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I created a CMDHandler class to handle all my CMD commands i'm having in my project.

For example:

CMDHandler.Run("/c  \"" + DWClientSetupChainerV1 + "\"");

CMDHandler.Run("taskkill /F /IM \"DWClientSetupChainerV1 .exe\"");

Though it seems like the process of my CMDHandler is never closed and therefore it's not able to start a second one. Does someone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?
FYI: The Exitcode is not always been used.

```
namespace Automated_Tests
{
    class CMDHandler
    { 
        private static readonly ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.Create(typeof(Program));

        public int Run(string command)
        {
            var proc = new Process();

            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "CMD",
                    Arguments = command,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
                proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
                proc.WaitForExit();

                return proc.ExitCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                proc.Close();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you pass as `command`? (`CMD.EXE` needs the `/c` parameter to execute other commands; like say `cmd.exe /c <mycommand>`). And for most uses `cmd.exe` is not required as a wrapper (unless you start batch files).

Comment: I'm trying to start an executable and close it afterwards again: 

"/c  \"" + DWClientSetupChainerV1 + "\"" and afterwards
"taskkill /F /IM \"DWClientSetupChainerV1.exe\""

Comment: You should add that information to your question. Other than that, to run `taskkill` you don't need `cmd.exe`. Either use (exemplary) `FileName = "taskkill"`, `Arguments = "/F /IM \"...\""` or `FileName = "cmd"`, `Arguments = "/c " + command` (passing what you do in `commands`).

Comment: Doesn't `WaitForExit` block the current Thread? Are you using a seperate Thread for the second call to `Run`?

Comment: Hey Thomas, no it's not blocking. A separate Thread is made.

Comment: How easy would it be to kill the Process using `Process.Kill()` from C# directly? Worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by creating separate tasks for my CMDHandler.Run method:

```
Task setupTask = new Task(() => CMDHandler.Run("/c  \"" + DWClientSetupChainerV1 + "\""));
setupTask.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
Task killSetupTask = new Task(() => CMDHandler.Run("/c taskkill /F /IM \"DWClientSetupChainerV1.exe\"", true));
killSetupTask.Start();
Task.WaitAll(setupTask, killSetupTask);
```